# Why am I getting a "Objects are not valid as a React child" error? I'm not passing an object

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning, and having an issue with this error. My intention is for payrate to act as the parent, with to child components. Timer sets a timer when the button is clicked, and ./today displays the gross pay. The gross pay is calculated in the parent ./payrate component, using timer and user input as props.The reason I'm using today as a child component, is because I may add functionality to it in the future.

I am using React JS and Vite. No backend, I intend to add localStorage to this later on.

I am trying to calculate the gross pay in the parent component, and use it as props to display in the child component. But i can't get rid of this "Objects are not valid as a React child" error. Can any of you see why I am getting this error, and how I can fix this?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Timer from './timer';
import TodaysPay from './today';

const PayRate = (props) => { 
   // handles the form         
  const [inputRate, setInputRate] = useState('');

  const handleRate = (event) => {
      setInputRate(event.target.value);
    }

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(`hourly rate is ${inputRate}`);
  }
// this calculates the hourly pay into seconds
    const {seconds} = props;
    const grossPay = (inputRate / 3600) * seconds; 
  
// end pay calculation
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        {inputRate}
      </h1>
      <TodaysPay grossPay={grossPay} />
      <Timer />
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input placeholder="Hourly Rate" type="number" value={inputRate} onChange={handleRate} />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
  export default PayRate;
```

```
import React from 'react'
import PayRate from './payrate';

// displays the grosspay, calculated in ./payrate.jsx
export default function TodaysPay(props) {
  const grossPay = props;
  return (
    <div>
      {grossPay}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have been using chatGPT and it got me to where my code snippets are now, but I still have the error. I have also been using google, but I can't find answer that seem relevant to my code. I did have more props in the TodaysPay attrubutes, but realized I didn't need them, so i removed them, but it didn't help.

Comment: You are not using `PayRate.jsx `. And if you have to use the `grossPay ` then the component has to return that and then only you can consume.

Answer (score 1):

`props` is an object in function components (TodaysPay)

this line: `const grossPay = props;`

should be: `const { grossPay } = props;` or `const grossPay = props.grossPay;`

or

```
export default function TodaysPay({ grossPay }) {
    return (
      <div>
        {grossPay}
      </div>
    )
}
```